# How to create a variable inside observeEvent function which when changes affect the whole program in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a reactive variable in server function of shiny code. This variable contains the path. It is supposed to change according to the user's input.
My code is :-
ui code:

```
map<-function(){   # A function to display pop up in summary tab for director where he/she can select the school name
    modalDialog(          
      fade = FALSE,
      footer = modalButton("Confirm"),
      title = 'Select the School',
      selectInput("school_name", "Choose the school",choices=c('XYZ','ABC'),selected = 'XYZ'),
      easyClose = FALSE,
      #footer = NULL,
      size = 'l')
  }
```

Server side code:

```
filepath <- reactiveVal("IS_XYZSchool.xlsx")
observeEvent(input$school_name,{
    
    pat<-dir(pattern = input$school_name)
    print(pat)
    filepath(pat)
    
  })
```

Now many other graphs and data is dependent on this variable 'filepath'. I want all those to change when user choose some other school_name. I've already initialized the first value for filepath. So it works for that value. But when i change the school_name, accordingly filepath should also change. But it throws an error. Here pat variable I've used to find the file related to the variable. I have two files in working directory IS_XYZSchool.xlsx and IS_ABCSchool.xlsx.

Comment: Hey...Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating a reactive object like this would help.

```
filepath <- reactive({
  readxl::read_excel(sprintf('IS_%sSCHOOL.xlsx', input$school_name))
})
```

You can use `filepath()` to get the dataset.

Comment: Hey...Ronak. Can we please have a chat on linkedIn? https://www.linkedin.com/in/mausam-singh-80331a1ab/